# MailChimp: Bulk re-send opt-in mailout to all subscribers

Tags: mailchimp

A client of mine is planning to move from a WordPress newsletter plugin to MailChimp.

As a result we'd be importing all the subscribers from the old system into MailChimp. However we have a feeling that a lot of those subscribers are either fake, dead emails, or not interested any more.

I was wondering whether there is any way to bulk resend an opt-in, so that all subscribers get a mail asking them to click a link to continue their subscription?

I didn't notice anything obvious when selecting all subscribers in a list on MailChimp

Answer (score 1):

At present, it doesn't seem as if there's any way to batch resend confirmation emails. To accomplish what you're after, you can use other mailchimp tools and external methods to clean your list up.

One way would be to contact your users and have them reconfirm. An example from a mailchimp knowledge base article:

> "Hi *|FNAME|*,
>
> Remember us? You visited our website back on *|OPTIN_DATE|* and signed up for our email newsletter. Well, we’ve finally gotten around to setting up a nifty email newsletter program, and we want to make sure you still want to hear from us. We hope you do, because every month or so our newsletter will include useful how-tos, tips, and advice (plus special offers like the one below).
>
> If you want to stay on our list, click here to renew your subscription! Of course, we don’t want to clog up your inbox with stuff you don’t want. If you're not interested, you can ignore this and you’ll never hear from us again…"

You can also remove people who haven't clicked on the last N campaigns, remove low-rating users, or use another way to remove people who aren't engaging.

Some helpful links:

- http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-can-i-remove-someone-from-my-list-who-has-never-opened-a-campaign/
- http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-can-i-remove-someone-from-my-list-who-has-never-opened-a-campaign/#open
- http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-can-i-remove-someone-from-my-list-who-has-never-opened-a-campaign/#rating